# Multiple strange errors when trying to import React component from local npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

I have a npm package of React components and an example Meteor.js app which will be used to display their usage. To install my local npm package I ran `npm install --save ../library` and it successfully added the dependency as `"library": "file:///path/to/lib"`.

However, when I import one of the components and try to use them, the console spams 29 errors, starting with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError:
    Unexpected token import
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'Random' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: 
    Cannot read property 'MongoID' of undefined
```

The code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Button from 'library/components/button/Button.jsx'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <Button>Click Me</Button>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Removing the `<Button/>` component and it's import removes the error. What is going on here?

**EDIT:** Digging deeper, if I click on the `Unexpected token import` error, it shows me the line where I import React in my libraries `Button` component. Could the issue be related to it somehow not understanding ES6 imports properly?

Comment: Yes it could be because of es6, you need to compile es6 to es5. With something like babel/browserify for example.

Comment: @OlivierKrull Meteor does this automatically. I am using ES6 throughout my app without any extra dependencies.